# ¿Existe algún término para describir a aquel que tiene el mismo apodo que uno?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, nombres-propios

Todos sabemos que [*tocayo*](https://dle.rae.es/tocayo) describe *Respecto de una persona, otra que tiene su mismo nombre*. Sin embargo, ¿existe algún término para describir lo mismo pero con apodos?

La duda me surge tras encontrar en la Wikipedia la existencia de dos futbolistas con el mismo nombre y apodo. Efectivamente, en la [página de desambiguación *Simeone*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeone) leemos:

> - Carmelo Simeone (1934-2014), exfutbolista argentino, defensa. Apodado *Cholo*.
> - Diego Pablo Simeone (1970-), exfutbolista y entrenador argentino, centrocampista. Apodado también como *El Cholo*.

¿Existe algún término para definir la relación apodística de estas dos personas (independientemente de que tengan el mismo apellido?

Comment: ¿Tocayo en segundo grado? (jaja, no se. La pregunta es muy buena, porque si no está ¡a esa palabra hay que inventarla!

Comment: (pensandolo mejor, lo de segundo grado —que era en broma— tampoco correspondería, se necesita una "tocayez apodística" pura, ya que si bien algunos apodos corresponden  al nombre (Alberto - Beto, Ignacio - Nacho, etc), los hay otros sobre una variedad grande de razones (características personales, anecdóticas, etc)

Comment: No creo que exista la palabra para eso pero de igual forma esta pregunta me dió la oportunidad de aprender una nueva palabra [Colombroño](https://dle.rae.es/colombro%C3%B1o)

Comment: @DGaleano tremenda palabra, no la conocía. Me quedé de piedra con la etimología: _De con y nombre_, no la veo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi propuesta es:

- Tocayos por el apodo / Tocayos por el sobrenombre.

En Internet encuentro esta frase para aludir a quienes comparten el apellido:

> [image: tocayos]
>
> ¡Anda que no!, pensé. El cliente y yo, tocayos por el patronímico. Casi parientes, como quien dice.

También encontré "tocayos por el segundo nombre".

Por lo tanto, creo que el recurso de aclarar "tocayos por XXX" sería válido para el caso en cuestión.

Comment: Me gusta la idea de utilizar _tocayo por X_ y añadirle la coletilla correspondiente, creo que está muy bien visto y se entiende fácil.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que no existe una palabra para describir con precisión la correspondencia de apodos. Pero como el lenguaje opera con el pensamiento, capaz de saltos y licencias para cubrir patrones comunes y extender su significado en cuestiones esenciales,  muchos entenderían la denominación de tocayo para estos homónimos.

> [homónimo](https://dle.rae.es/hom%C3%B3nimo?m=form)
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona o de una cosa: Que, con respecto de otra, tiene el mismo nombre. U. t. c. s.

Ergo, si tenemos entre los conocidos dos personas apodadas "Chueco", (aunque uno se llame Pedro y otro Juan), es entendible y natural poder también referirnos a ambos como *tocayos* ('*de apodo*')

Se puede ver que hay combinaciones posibles de esa homonimia:

- **total** ("*tocayo doble*", una como si fuera una especie de '*tocayo en segundo grado*) donde coinciden tanto el nombre como el apodo; — lo cual es común por que hay muchos sobrenombres institucionalizados, sea basados en su sonoridad o la costumbre (*Alberto - Beto*, *Francisco- Paco/Pancho*, Ignacio - Nacho,  etc), o
- **parcial**, donde hablamos de tocayez

  1. por el nombre ("*tocayo*"), en el sentido clásico.
  2. por el apodo ("*tocayo de apodo*"), una "tocayez apodística" —donde la coincidencia se da únicamente en el apodo (por el pseudónimo o alias) usado.